# How to integrate the $L^2$ function $1/|x|$ numerically

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, numerical-integration

Let $f=\frac{1}{|x|},x\in\mathbb{R^3}$ and $\Omega=[-b,b]^3$. How to construct a quadrature scheme to solve 
$$
\int_\Omega f\phi\psi dx\quad ?
$$ 
where $\phi\psi$ is smooth function.

I know there exists a transformation called Duffy transformation which can eliminate the singularity at $x=0$ by using the jacobian. Indeed, let $$\begin{aligned}T&=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3);0\leq x_1\leq 1,0\leq x_2\leq x_1,0\leq x_3\leq x_1\}\\ \hat{T}&=\{(\hat{x}_1,\hat{x}_2,\hat{x}_3);0\leq \hat{x}_1\leq 1,0\leq\hat{x_2}\leq1,0\leq\hat{x_3}\leq 1\}\end{aligned}$$

Define $F:\hat{T}\rightarrow T$ as 
$$
F(\hat{x}_1,\hat{x}_2,\hat{x}_3)=(\hat{x}_1,\hat{x}_1\hat{x}_2,\hat{x}_1\hat{x}_3)
$$
Then 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{T}\frac{1}{|x|}\phi\psi dx&=\int_{\hat{T}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}}\phi\cdot\psi(x)dx
=\int_{\hat{T}}\frac{\phi\cdot\psi(\hat{x_1},\hat{x}_1\hat{x}_2,\hat{x}_1\hat{x}_3)}{\sqrt{\hat{x}_1^2+\hat{x}_1^2\hat{x}_2^2+\hat{x}_1^2\hat{x}_3^2}}\hat{x}_1^2d\hat{x}\\
&=\int_\hat{T}\frac{\hat{x}_1\phi\cdot\psi(\hat{x_1},\hat{x}_1\hat{x}_2,\hat{x}_1\hat{x}_3)}{\sqrt{1+\hat{x}_2^2+\hat{x}_3^2}}d\hat{x}
\end{aligned}
$$ 
which can be solved by usual quadrature scheme.

On the other hand, someone can also avoid the singularity by omitting a $\varepsilon$ cube which contains the origin.

However, these are not enough for me when I want to study the convergence rate of numerical integration on $\Omega$. I hope the error can be bounded by $O(h)\Vert \phi\Vert_{1,2,\Omega}\Vert \psi\Vert_{1,2,\Omega}$

Is there any other way to integrate a $L^2$ function or a function with singularity at vertex directly with the error bounded by $L^2$ norm?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you omit an $\varepsilon$ cube from the domain, call it $E\subset \Omega$, then using Cauchy-Schwarz the error due to this omission is bounded by $\|f\|_E \|g\|_E \le O(\varepsilon^2) \|g\|_\Omega$. Would that be sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: Sorry, I wrongly estimated the norm $\|f\|_E$ (used $L^1$ instead of $L^2$). The correct $L^2$ norm is $O(\sqrt{\varepsilon})$.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Well... I think there is a little mistake. $O(\sqrt{\varepsilon})$ might can not be obtained by using holder inequality.

Comment: there might always be a mistake, though I don't see it right now. What is your estimate for the $L^2$ norm $\|f\|_E$? Whatever it is, it should go to $0$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Why not split g into $g(x)=g(0)+g(x)-g(0)$ and handle the $g(0)$ part separately?

Comment: @MichaelRenardy I don't understand what's you say. Could you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: What I mean is, separate out the singular part and deal with it analytically.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy But we still need to caluculate $\int_\Omega\frac{g(x)+g(0)}{|x|}$ numerically?

Comment: Do you want an error estimate for Duffy's method, or do you want a method other than Duffy's?

Comment: @timur I hope to find a method other than Duffy's. The error estimate for Duffy' method I obtain can not be bounded by $O(h)\Vert\phi\Vert_{2}\Vert\psi\Vert_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Michael Renardy's suggestion, write $g=\phi\psi$, and write
$$
g(x)=g(0)+x\cdot G(x) ,
$$
where $G$ is a smooth function. Then the integral becomes
$$
\int_\Omega fg = g(0)\int_\Omega f + \sum_i\int_\Omega \frac{x_i}{|x|}G_i(x)d^3x .
$$
The integrands in the latter integrals are bounded, and the first integral can be written as
$$
\int_\Omega f = \int_{B_r}f + \int_{\Omega\setminus B_r}f ,
$$
where the first can be computed analytically, and the second has a smooth integrand. Here $B_r$ is some ball centred at the origin.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But the first integral may not be computed analytically sometimes due to the boundary, isn't it?

Comment: @whereamI look at the edit

Comment: Well.. I think the error of the first part $g(0)\int_\Omega f$ can still not be bounded by $\Vert\phi\Vert_2\Vert\psi\Vert_2$. Anyway, thank you very much, it gives me some ideas.

Comment: @whereamI: Even the value of the integral itself cannot be bounded by that, because that would imply that $f$ is bounded.

Comment: Why do you think if the integral bounded by that then $f$ is bounded? Could you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: @whereamI: That's because $L^\infty(\Omega)$ is the dual of $L^1(\Omega)$. If $T:L^1\to\mathbb{R}$ is a bounded linear map then there is $f\in L^\infty$ such that $T(g)=\int fg$.